# Accessing Active Directory Records Via ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory, windows-authentication

Seems like my local machine does not have the required permissions to write data into the Active Directory. I can read data but can not change and update it. Upon calling the .save() command I receive the next message: "Access is denied".

I do not use any login details in order to log into the Active Directory and I wish not to use any as well. I know it has something to do with the application pools and IIS generally, but I can't seem to find a working solution other than trying and changing some minor options and features.

EDIT:
This is the code I'm trying to execute:

```
using (PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "DOMAINANME"))
{
    GroupPrincipal group = new GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, "GROUPNAME");
    group.Members.Remove(pc, IdentityType.SamAccountName, "USERNAME");
    group.Save();
}
```

Comment: I think you have to use login details of some sort.  Otherwise, asp.net will run in the security context of the app pool which will by default have very low permissions (as it should).  I think you can do this by using active directory as your membership provider.

Comment: @sovemp and how do I do that? I can't seem to find the correct provider.

Comment: If you set authentication mode to windows (and authorization to deny all unauthenticated users), this will force the browser to ask for an AD login.  EDIT:  Also, I agree with Zychia's suggestion to make an intranet-only layer if you don't want to be prompting for logins.

Comment: @sovemp I denied all anonymous users and still - no promt for AD login when I apply the .save() method. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you doing it from your local computer?  It won't actually prompt until you deploy it somewhere within the domain, I think.

Comment: Also, another quick thing I just remembered.  You could look at the AD membership provider (although it does require full trust).  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.activedirectorymembershipprovider(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @TommyNaidich If you are not being prompted to log into the web application when you run it, make sure that IIS is configured to require Windows authentication - and anonymous access is disabled. (I've updated my answer to include this.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to execute code that needs specific permissions to your Active Directory, follow these steps:

1. Require the user to log into the ASP.NET application.
2. Have your code impersonate the currently-logged in user when executing the the Active Directory portion that needs that access.

There may be slight variations depending on the version of ASP.NET you are using, but basically...

### Step 1

For the user login, just use the standard ASP.NET authentication configuration. Because it's the easiest to configure (and just works with AD) I'll document Windows Authentication here. This will prompt the user with a standard Windows login dialog box - where they will need to enter their domain credentials. To configure the application, make the following changes to the Web.config

```
<configuration>
  ...
  <system.web>
    ...
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    ...
  </system.web>
  ...
</configuration>
```

By default, ASP.NET should already know how to talk to the Active Directory when configured for Windows Authentication, so nothing else should be required, but if you find you need a separate *Role Provider*, feel free to take [the one we use](https://github.com/BellevueCollege/CtcApi/blob/dev/CtcApi/Web/Security/ActiveDirectoryRoleProvider.cs). (We also have [instructions](https://github.com/BellevueCollege/CtcApi/wiki/CtcApi.Web.Security#wiki-activedirectoryroleprovider).) But again, you shouldn't need it.

Edit: You also need to make sure IIS is configured - using `inetmgr.exe` - to not allow anonymous access for the application. Otherwise, it will never prompt the user to log in. We typically disable *Anonymous* access and enable *Windows* and *Basic* authentication - because we need to support browsers that don't support NTLM.

### Step 2

Now that you have an authenticated user, you can programmatically impersonate them. The following is adapted from [Impersonating the authenticating user in code](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306158#3):

```
System.Security.Principal.WindowsImpersonationContext impersonationContext;
impersonationContext = ((System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity)User.Identity).Impersonate();

try
{
    // Do your writing to the AD here
}
finally
{
    impersonationContext.Undo();
}
```

I also just discovered (while searching for reference links for this answer) that this is all pretty well documented in the MSDN article [How To: Use Windows Authentication in ASP.NET 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647405.aspx)

Let us know how it goes :-)

Comment: I'm getting the next error when I put the code I'm trying to execute (main post) in between your /try/ block: An operations error occurred. It also marks the first line of my code (GroupPrincipal group..) as the one causing the issue.

Comment: @TommyNaidich Errors communicating with Active Directory can be really difficult to troubleshoot. I'd first verify that 1) the code running inside the `try` block is executing as the user you expect. If you can debug the code in action, check the values of the `impersonationContext`. (I'm not at a computer where I can verify this right now, but there should be some properties inside it somewhere that allow you to see the username, etc.) And, 2) ensure the user you're impersonating has the permissions needed.

Can you post a copy of the exact error?

Comment: I'd also recommend only impersonating for the code that actually needs it - so only wrap the `group.Save()` call in the `try` block. The idea is to keep elevated privileges to a minimum.

Answer (score 5):

Your intuition is correct - you need proper permissions on the application pool account.

A simplest way would be:

1. Create a new domain user account
2. Add it to "Domain admins" group
3. In your iis server, locate the pool your application uses and change the pool identity to the newly created user

This way all requests from users to iis are run in the context of the domain admin and thus all requests from iis to AD will succeed - domain admins can operate the AD.

Although the above solution would work, it is probably not recommended. This is because the application does many things other than just connecting to the AD and if there are places that can be misused, you risk running unwanted requests in the domain admin context.

Usually then, such application would have **two** layers, a front layer and a back layer. The front layer runs in a restricted context and is responsible for all user requests. This is your application. A back layer is **another** web application that is not accessible from internet, only from the local intranet. This application runs in the domain admin context and serves as the gateway to the AD. The front application uses the back application to talk to the AD.

Comment: My main problem is that I am not allowed to create login users. I can, however, request the user to type in his Windows login details and work with that. Sadly I do not know how to pull this off.

Comment: If you set the domain admin account as a pool identity then creating new users doesn't works? Sounds almost impossible or you have another unrelated issue.